# How to use Vuex to set items in Vuetify data table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

i am making an API request to return an array of objects and it looks something like this:

```
enter code here
  returnedMyArray [
        {
         name: 'David', 
         age: '25', 
         hobby: 'Music'
         },
         {
         name: 'Mary', 
         age: '28', 
         hobby: 'Cooking'
         }]
```

I want to capture this state in Vuex store and use getters and setters to display the data in  my Data-Table component but not sure how would i go about it.

My Data table component looks like this.

```
enter code here
 <template>
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="tableItems">
  <template v-slot:items="props">
     <td>{{props.tableItems.name}} </td>
      <td>{{props.tableItems.age}} </td>
   </template>
</v-data-table>
 </template>

 <script>
   import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
   export default{
       data() {
         return {
           headers: [
           { text: 'Person', sortable: false },
           { text: 'Age group', sortable: false },
           { text: 'Activity', sortable: false },
               ]
          }
         }
       },
      computed: {
         ...mapGetters({ 
       tableItems: 'tableItems'
       })
          }
 </script>
```

And My store looks like this:-

```
     state: {
     items: []
    },
    getters: {
      tableItems: state => state.items
    }
```

I am not quite sure if i am taking the right approach or if i need to set up a mutation, any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you need to create mutations. The only way to actually change state in a Vuex store is by committing a mutation. So set your mutations like this:

```
const mutations = {
    setItems: (state, payload) => {
        state.items = payload;
    }
}
```

- [More about mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html)

Not sure from where you are calling your API. But [`Actions`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) are a good place to call your APIs. Note You can not call your API inside `Mutations`, since `Mutations` are synchronous. But `Actions` are asynchronous, so you can call your APIs from them.

```
const actions = {
    setItems: (context, payload) => {
        //if any payload is passed to this action, 
        //it will commit the payload to the "setItems" mutations
        if (payload) {
            context.commit("setItems", payload);
            return;
        }
        //if no payload is passed, it will call the API
        else {
            //here I'm using "Vue Resource", you can use
            //any package like "axios" etc.
            Vue.$http.get(`https://example.com/getItems`).then(
                (response) => {
                    context.commit("setItems", response.body);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing is, if you want to use the state without any manipulations, instead of `mapGetters`, use directly [`mapState`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper). `mapGetters` are handy when you need the manipulated data (but the state will be unchanged). Like, a simple case, you need the state_value multiplied by 3, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sorry and yeah i should have added the code for the API request but i set it up as you suggested and i am getting an empty array in the table items.